# How to Throw a InvalidLockCombinationException

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, methods

i Have the following code but i am confused how i throw the InvalidLockCombinationException. This
exception   (which  should  not have    any methods)    will    indicate    that    an  attempt to  assign  a
combination to  a   lock    failed  (thus   making  the combination invalid for that    lock). If   the combination is  invalid 
(if not all its numbers are in  the dial)   then    the constructor should  throw   a   new 
InvalidLockCombinationException.    By  throwing    this    exception   we  can avoid   creating    locks   with
invalid combinations    (which  in  real    life    will    be  defective). All locks   are open    when    created this is what i have so far. Any help would be appreciated on how to get the exception working.

```
    public class Lock{
    public Combination correct;
    public int upperLimit;
    public boolean isOpen;

    public Lock(int aLimit, Combination aCombo) throws InvalidLockCombinationException(){
    correct = aCombo;
    upperLimit = aLimit;
    isOpen=true;    
    int[] comboHolder = new int[3];
    comboHolder = aCombo.getNumbers();      
        for(int i=0; i<comboHolder.length;i++){
            if(comboHolder[i]<0 || comboHolder[i]>upperLimit){
                throw InvalidLockCombinationException;


}
}   
}
}
```

Comment: Exceptions are Objects too. They need to be instantiated.

Comment: @A--C And programmers are people as well. They need to be fed :)

Comment: @hexafraction, can't he even use an IDE to code which would red mark the line instantly right after putting the `;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception is an object too. You can't really throw the idea of a ball, you need an actual ball to throw.

```
 throw new InvalidLockCombinationException();
```

Nullary constructor given since you said it should be a basic exception sans extra fields or methods. I would still try to accept a String message for extra info but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

I recommend using an actual IDE. It would politely tell you about what's happening with its red mark.